# Datalist not getting bound properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have following datalist:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlMovieImages" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="6"
                                    Width="100%">

                                    <ItemTemplate   >
                                        <div class="creamebox w49" id="inDiv" runat="server">
                                            <table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" style="padding-top: 10px">
                                                 <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">
                                                     <asp:Label ID="lblMovieName" runat="server" CssClass="NormalTextBig" Visible="false">MovieName</asp:Label>                                                </td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>

                                                   <td align="left" colspan="2" valign="top">
                                                     <asp:Image ID="imgSmall" runat="server" width="150" Height="200"  Visible="false"/> 
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FUImage" runat="server" CssClass="NormalText"  Visible="false"/>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpload" runat="server" CssClass="JustLinks" CommandName="Upload" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MovieID") %>'  Visible="false">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </td>

                                                </tr>

                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                    </asp:DataList>
```

**Binding it with following code:**

```
 If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

                If rbMovies.SelectedValue = "0" Then
                    flag = True
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/MoviePoster/" & e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & "_L.jpg")) And System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/MoviePoster/" & e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & "_S.jpg")) Then
                        CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblMovieName"), Label).Text = e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & ". " & e.Item.DataItem("moviename")
                        CType(e.Item.FindControl("imgSmall"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).ImageUrl = "~/MoviePoster/" & e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & "_S.jpg"
                    Else
                        TotalnoImage += 1
                        CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblMovieName"), Label).Text = e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & ". " & e.Item.DataItem("moviename")
                        CType(e.Item.FindControl("imgSmall"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).ImageUrl = "~/MoviePoster/" & "no_image_S.jpg"
                    End If
                End If

                Dim divControl As HtmlGenericControl = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("inDiv"), HtmlGenericControl)

                If rbMovies.SelectedValue = "1" Then
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/MoviePoster/" & e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & "_L.jpg")) And System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/MoviePoster/" & e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & "_S.jpg")) Then
                        divControl.Visible = False
                    Else
                        divControl.Visible = True
                        flag = True
                        TotalnoImage += 1
                        CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblMovieName"), Label).Text = e.Item.DataItem("movieid") & ". " & e.Item.DataItem("moviename")
                        CType(e.Item.FindControl("imgSmall"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).ImageUrl = "~/MoviePoster/" & "no_image_S.jpg"
                    End If
                End If

                If flag = True Then
                    CType(e.Item.FindControl("imgSmall"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).Visible = True
                    CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblMovieName"), Label).Visible = True
                    CType(e.Item.FindControl("FUImage"), FileUpload).Visible = True
                    CType(e.Item.FindControl("lnkUpload"), LinkButton).Visible = True
                End If

            End If
```

When rbMovies="0" i want to show all the images in the folder and when rbMovies="1" only one particular image i.e. "noimage".

When Datalist is getting bound, it shows me as follows:

[image]

where noimage is not applicable it shows blank item, as shown in 3 rd and after 10th..

I want it to be in one line.

plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a css class on the table that has a property display:hidden

mytable.hidden {visibility:hidden;}

also add a runat="server" on the table and give it a name.
You can add/remove the cssclass in codebehind